# After updating to 22.04, programs crash frequently. On startup: 'AtributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'isAlive'

Tags: updates, python, dell, snap, 22.04

Initially, this problem only affected Firefox, but it got better after I uninstalled snaps and reinstalled the old version. Now, everything seems to be crashing (python, zoom, terminal, chrome, even the OS). On startup, I get the following warning:[image]

Is anyone else having these issue? Is there a fix? It is becoming a serious problem as I cannot stay in a Zoom meeting for more than 10 minutes at a time without the program crashing, nor can I run any python code on my computer that takes longer than ~10 minutes to run on my machine.

Comment: Have you somehow messed with python like trying to install a new version?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I uninstalled and reinstalled jupyter a couple of times, but not python